# Composite USB CDC/HID device on STMF32F303

Tags: usb, stm32, hid, usbserial, cdc

I'm following the advice:

> It is possible to achieve your own composite USB Device, by combining the desired classes' drivers into one class, under your own folder within: Middlewares\ST\STM32_USB Device Library\Class

from https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkgYtSAJ/stm32f4-hal-composite-usb-device-example

I now have a unified configuration descriptor.

```
/* USB CDC device Configuration Descriptor */
__ALIGN_BEGIN uint8_t USBD_CDC_CfgFSDesc[USB_CDC_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ] __ALIGN_END =
{
  /*Configuration Descriptor*/
  0x09,   /* bLength: Configuration Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_CONFIGURATION,      /* bDescriptorType: Configuration */
  USB_CDC_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ,                /* wTotalLength:no of returned bytes */
  0x00,
  0x03,   /* bNumInterfaces: 2 interface */
  0x01,   /* bConfigurationValue: Configuration value */
  0x00,   /* iConfiguration: Index of string descriptor describing the configuration */
  0xC0,   /* bmAttributes: self powered */
  0x32,   /* MaxPower 0 mA */

  /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //Add 1 IAD class here // this one is for COM port
  0x08, // bLength: Interface Descriptor size
  0x0B, // bDescriptorType: IAD
  0x00, // bFirstInterface                                  //starting of interface
  0x02, // bInterfaceCount                                  //interfaces under this IAD class
  0x02, // bFunctionClass: CDC
  0x02, // bFunctionSubClass
  0x01, // bFunctionProtocol
  0x02, // iFunction
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /*Interface Descriptor */
  0x09,   /* bLength: Interface Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: Interface */
  /* Interface descriptor type */
  0x00,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
  0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
  0x01,   /* bNumEndpoints: One endpoints used */
  0x02,   /* bInterfaceClass: Communication Interface Class */
  0x02,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: Abstract Control Model */
  0x01,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: Common AT commands */
  0x00,   /* iInterface: */

  /*Header Functional Descriptor*/
  0x05,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
  0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
  0x00,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Header Func Desc */
  0x10,   /* bcdCDC: spec release number */
  0x01,

  /*Call Management Functional Descriptor*/
  0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
  0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
  0x01,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Call Management Func Desc */
  0x00,   /* bmCapabilities: D0+D1 */
  0x01,   /* bDataInterface: 1 */

  /*ACM Functional Descriptor*/
  0x04,   /* bFunctionLength */
  0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
  0x02,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Abstract Control Management desc */
  0x02,   /* bmCapabilities */

  /*Union Functional Descriptor*/
  0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
  0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
  0x06,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Union func desc */
  0x00,   /* bMasterInterface: Communication class interface */
  0x01,   /* bSlaveInterface0: Data Class Interface */

  /*Endpoint 2 Descriptor*/
  0x07,                           /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,   /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
  CDC_CMD_EP,                     /* bEndpointAddress */
  0x03,                           /* bmAttributes: Interrupt */
  LOBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),     /* wMaxPacketSize: */
  HIBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),
  CDC_FS_BINTERVAL,                           /* bInterval: */
  /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  /*Data class interface descriptor*/
  0x09,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: */
  0x01,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
  0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
  0x02,   /* bNumEndpoints: Two endpoints used */
  0x0A,   /* bInterfaceClass: CDC */
  0x00,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: */
  0x00,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: */
  0x00,   /* iInterface: */

  /*Endpoint OUT Descriptor*/
  0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,      /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
  CDC_OUT_EP,                        /* bEndpointAddress */
  0x02,                              /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
  LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
  HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
  0x00,                              /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */

  /*Endpoint IN Descriptor*/
  0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
  USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,      /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
  CDC_IN_EP,                         /* bEndpointAddress */
  0x02,                              /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
  LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
  HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
  0x00,                               /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // IAD      Mouse
  0x08, // bLength: Interface Descriptor size
  0x0B, // bDescriptorType: IAD
  0x02, // bFirstInterface                    //starts from zero .. hence 0-1- and now 2
  0x01, // bInterfaceCount                    //no of interfaces used in function. for above cdc it was 2
  0x03,   //*bInterfaceClass: HID*/
  0x01,   //*bInterfaceSubClass : 1=BOOT, 0=no boot*/
  0x02,   //*nInterfaceProtocol : 0=none, 1=keyboard, 2=mouse*/
  0x02,   //*iInterface: Index of string descriptor*/
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /************** Descriptor of Joystick Mouse interface ****************/
  /* 09 */
  0x09,         /*bLength: Interface Descriptor size*/
  USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,/*bDescriptorType: Interface descriptor type*/
  0x02,         /*bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface*/
  0x00,         /*bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting*/
  0x01,         /*bNumEndpoints*/
  0x03,         /*bInterfaceClass: HID*/
  0x01,         /*bInterfaceSubClass : 1=BOOT, 0=no boot*/
  0x02,         /*nInterfaceProtocol : 0=none, 1=keyboard, 2=mouse*/
  0x02,            /*iInterface: Index of string descriptor*/
  /******************** Descriptor of Joystick Mouse HID ********************/
  /* 18 */
  0x09,         /*bLength: HID Descriptor size*/
  HID_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, /*bDescriptorType: HID*/
  0x11,         /*bcdHID: HID Class Spec release number*/
  0x01,
  0x00,         /*bCountryCode: Hardware target country*/
  0x01,         /*bNumDescriptors: Number of HID class descriptors to follow*/
  0x22,         /*bDescriptorType*/
  HID_MOUSE_REPORT_DESC_SIZE,/*wItemLength: Total length of Report descriptor*/
  0x00,
  /******************** Descriptor of Mouse endpoint ********************/
  /* 27 */
  0x07,          /*bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size*/
  USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT, /*bDescriptorType:*/

  HID_EPIN_ADDR,     /*bEndpointAddress: Endpoint Address (IN)*/
  0x03,            /*bmAttributes: Interrupt endpoint*/
  HID_EPIN_SIZE, /*wMaxPacketSize: 4 Byte max */
  0x00,
  HID_FS_BINTERVAL,          /*bInterval: Polling Interval */
  /* 34 */

} ;
```

and a unified init:

```
static uint8_t  USBD_CDC_Init(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev, uint8_t cfgidx)
{
  uint8_t ret = 0U;
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef   *hcdc;

  if (pdev->dev_speed == USBD_SPEED_HIGH)
  {
    /* Open EP IN */
    USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, CDC_IN_EP, USBD_EP_TYPE_BULK,
                   CDC_DATA_HS_IN_PACKET_SIZE);

    pdev->ep_in[CDC_IN_EP & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

    /* Open EP OUT */
    USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, CDC_OUT_EP, USBD_EP_TYPE_BULK,
                   CDC_DATA_HS_OUT_PACKET_SIZE);

    pdev->ep_out[CDC_OUT_EP & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

  }
  else
  {
    /* Open EP IN */
    USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, CDC_IN_EP, USBD_EP_TYPE_BULK,
                   CDC_DATA_FS_IN_PACKET_SIZE);

    pdev->ep_in[CDC_IN_EP & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

    /* Open EP OUT */
    USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, CDC_OUT_EP, USBD_EP_TYPE_BULK,
                   CDC_DATA_FS_OUT_PACKET_SIZE);

    pdev->ep_out[CDC_OUT_EP & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;
  }
  /* Open Command IN EP */
  USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, CDC_CMD_EP, USBD_EP_TYPE_INTR, CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE);
  pdev->ep_in[CDC_CMD_EP & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

  pdev->pClassData = USBD_malloc(sizeof(USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef));

  if (pdev->pClassData == NULL)
  {
    ret = 1U;
  }
  else
  {
    hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *) pdev->pClassData;

    /* Init  physical Interface components */
    ((USBD_CDC_ItfTypeDef *)pdev->pUserData)->Init();

    /* Init Xfer states */
    hcdc->TxState = 0U;
    hcdc->RxState = 0U;

    if (pdev->dev_speed == USBD_SPEED_HIGH)
    {
      /* Prepare Out endpoint to receive next packet */
      USBD_LL_PrepareReceive(pdev, CDC_OUT_EP, hcdc->RxBuffer,
                             CDC_DATA_HS_OUT_PACKET_SIZE);
    }
    else
    {
      /* Prepare Out endpoint to receive next packet */
      USBD_LL_PrepareReceive(pdev, CDC_OUT_EP, hcdc->RxBuffer,
                             CDC_DATA_FS_OUT_PACKET_SIZE);
    }
  }

  // HID
  /* Open EP IN */
  USBD_LL_OpenEP(pdev, HID_EPIN_ADDR, USBD_EP_TYPE_INTR, HID_EPIN_SIZE);
  pdev->ep_in[HID_EPIN_ADDR & 0xFU].is_used = 1U;

  pdev->pClassData = USBD_malloc(sizeof(USBD_HID_HandleTypeDef));

  if (pdev->pClassData == NULL)
  {
    return USBD_FAIL;
  }

  ((USBD_HID_HandleTypeDef *)pdev->pClassData)->state = HID_IDLE;

  return ret;
}
```

I am concerned that the value of `CDC_IN_EP` (0x81) clashes with `HID_EPIN_ADDR` (also 0x81).

Is this a valid concern?

Is there an example of making a composite CDC/HID using CubeMX?

Comment: Your concerns are valid. You'll need to use different endpoint addresses for your CDC and HID class. I don't know of any CubeMX examples which combine two classes. The main difficulty will most likely be getting all functionality (Init, Setup, Data Events...) into a single USBD_ClassTypeDef instance which you can then register to the device library.

Comment: If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `0x83` as the HID endpoint.  I confirmed that this worked in the simple HID example, too.

There are still many other obstacles in the way of getting a working CDC/HID composite device on STM32.